# Is the following conjecture true: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x'(x)}{x} = 1 \implies \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x')}{f(x)}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Is the following conjecture true?

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.
>   $$
> \text{If}\ \ \ \ x'/x \to 1 \text{ as } x \to \infty \quad \text{then} \quad f(x')/f(x) \to 1 \text{ as } x \to \infty.
> $$

EDIT: As pointed out by Haris, this statement is not true in general. But is it true if we in addition assume that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)/x^k \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

EDIT2: Domination by a polynomial is still not enough. But does it hold if we additionally assume that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: What is $x'$ supposed to be?

Comment: $x'$ is a sequence depending on $x$. $x'$ goes to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider as a counterexample the following:

$$f(x) = e^{x^3}$$

$$x' = \frac{1}{\sin(1/x)}$$

**Edit:** Even after your edit, the claim still doesn't hold. Consider the following example:

$$x'=x+1$$
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
  1,& \text{for } x \text{ even} \\
  x,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

**Edit 2:** Differentiability is still not enough:

$$x'=x+1$$
$$f(x)=x+x^2[1-\cos(\pi x)]$$

Notice that $x'$ is differentiable here as well.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks! Here an even simpler counter example: $x' = x+\sqrt{x}$ and $f(x)=e^x$. I have edited the question, because I am interested in $f$ where it is dominated by a polynomial.

Comment: @Danijel Look at my edit.

Comment: Ok and what if we additionally assume that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere. Made a secons edit.

Comment: @Danijel See my 2nd edit.

Comment: @Danijel Also, I took the  liberty to edit your question a little. If you don't like it, please tell me.

Comment: Oh still not enough... I have edited the title a bit further. I want to find conditions, where it does hold.

Comment: At this point, you've gotten correct answers to the question you asked, to a modified question, and to a further modified question. It's time to say "Yep, I give credit to this answerer, and now I'm going to think some more and ask a NEW question." Substantially changing a question after it's been answered is kind of rude -- it's a bait-and-switch.

Comment: Of course, sorry for that. I changed to the title to the previous version.

Comment: @Danijel Thank you. I do not mind answering the question, it is an interesting one. But, John is right that you should post another question. But take great care to phrase it well to attract people with more expertise than me. The last example I provided has functions as nice as I can think of: both $x'$ and $f$ are infinitely differentiable. As far as I can see, if the new question has an answer, the conditions given will probably be "artificial" and not very elegant.

Comment: @Haris, many thanks for your help! I will think more carefully before I formulate the new question!